# React JS - React-Router nested route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm new on React and I try to build my first application, for the route I used react-router and this is my App

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path='/' component={Container}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                    <Route path='/address' component={Address}>
                        <IndexRoute component={TwitterFeed} />
                        <Route path='instagram' component={Instagram} />
                        <Route path='query' component={Query} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path='/about/:name' component={About} /> 
                    <Route path='/namedComponent' component={NamedComponents}>
                        <IndexRoute components={{ title: Title, subTitle: SubTitle }} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Everything work well but not this line `<Route path='/about/:name' component={About} />`, in fact if i try to write /address/12345 white page appears to me whitout error, someone can help me?

This is my webpack.config.js

```
'use strict';
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {

    entry: {
        app: [
            './src/main.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path:     __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath : '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '[name].css', disable: false, allChunks: true})
    ] : [],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./dist",
        inline:      true,
        port:        3000,
    },
    //source map for js
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            //babel ECMAScript 6 compiler
            {
                test:   /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },

            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap' ] //sourceMap for debug css in devTools
                /*loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback : 'style-loader', use : 'css-loader?sourceMap!sass-loader?sourceMap'
                }) FOR PROD*/
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

And i use this script : `webpack-dev-server  --inline --content-base dist --history-api-fallback`

Comment: There's no route to handle  /address/12345 did you mean /about/12345?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I wanted to write /about/12345

Comment: What version react router you use ?

Comment: @GiangLe the version is 2.0.1

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0):

In your component "Container" you should have children object.

You can have a better look on the snippet bellow.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const BasicExample = () =>
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <Route to="/" component={ComponentThatHaveChildren} />
        <Route path="/path1/path2" component={ChildrenComponent} />
      </ul>
    </div>
  </Router>;

const ComponentThatHaveChildren = props =>
  <div>
    <h1>Component That Have Children</h1>
    <h2>{props.children}</h2>
  </div>;

const ChildrenComponent = () =>
  <div>
    <h2>Children</h2>
  </div>;

export default BasicExample;
```